# Comparing two distribution known by their deciles

Tags: kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I am trying to compare a travel time measuring device with a reference device. The assessed device only provide the decile (+min and max values) and not all the measured individual travel time.

I am considering to apply the Kolmogorov-Smirnov but instead of using the individual observations, I'd like to use the deciles of the two data series. Note that the series are of different sizes.

Alternatively, I could compare the assessed system deciles to the individual data points from the reference system. That more work since for each aggregation periods I have a lot of data but it should be doable.

Does it silly, or does it make sense ? If it doesn't make sense what test could I use ?